# React Redux thunk - Action is overriding unexpected information

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, thunk

im building a reddit clone, fetching top post. The app should have a favorites post CRUD.
So what i build is a two columns layout, left side is the post list and right part has  post detail OR favorites list when switch is ON.

All this is handled by two reducers: favorites and post. The issue is: when i fire set favorites action, this is overriding post data for some reason. I just reviewed the whole flow several times and i cant fine what is going on.

This is the redux dev tools state, with post fetched and then with show favorites action

[image]

[image]

This is favorites reducer:

```
import {
  FETCH_FAVORITES_REQUEST,
  FETCH_FAVORITES_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_FAVORITES_ERROR,
  SHOW_FAVORITES
} from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: false,
  show: false
};

const favorites = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_FAVORITES_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case FETCH_FAVORITES_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        data: action.payload
      };
    }
    case FETCH_FAVORITES_ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: true, isLoading: false };

    case SHOW_FAVORITES:
      return { ...state, show: !state.show };

    default:
      return initialState;
  }
};

export default favorites;
```

and this is posts reducer:

```
import {
  FETCH_POST_REQUEST,
  FETCH_POST_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_POST_ERROR,
  SET_READED,
  DISMISS_ALL,
  DISMISS_POST
} from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: false,
  lastFetched: null,
  allDismissed: false
};

const posts = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POST_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case FETCH_POST_SUCCESS: {
      const data = [...state.data, ...action.payload];
      return {
        ...state,
        data,
        lastFetched: action.lastFetched,
        isLoading: false,
        allDismissed: false
      };
    }
    case FETCH_POST_ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: true, isLoading: false };
    case SET_READED: {
      const newData = state.data;
      const foundIndex = newData.findIndex((x) => x.id === action.payload);
      newData[foundIndex].readed = true;
      return {
        ...state,
        data: newData
      };
    }
    case DISMISS_ALL: {
      return {
        ...state,
        allDismissed: true,
        data: []
      };
    }
    case DISMISS_POST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.filter((post) => post.id !== action.payload)
      };
    }

    default:
      return initialState;
  }
};

export default posts;
```

This is the component from where show favorites action is being dispatched:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';
import Toggle from 'react-toggle';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';

import { DEVICE_SIZE } from '../constants';
import { showFavorites } from '../actions/favorites';

const ToogleFavorites = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  text-align: end;
  z-index: 2;

  ${({ isMobile }) =>
    isMobile &&
    css`
      font-size: small;
    `}
`;

export default () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { show } = useSelector((state) => state.favorites);

  const isTabletOrBigger = useMediaQuery({ minDeviceWidth: DEVICE_SIZE.tablet });
  const handleToogle = () => dispatch(showFavorites());

  return (
    <ToogleFavorites isMobile={isTabletOrBigger}>
      <Toggle defaultChecked={show} onChange={handleToogle} />
      <div>Toogle favorites</div>
    </ToogleFavorites>
  );
};
```

favorites action (seems not big deal):

```
export const showFavorites = () => ({
  type: SHOW_FAVORITES
});
```

Let me know anything extra info. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your reducer has the default case to `return intialState` which means any action that isn't explicitly handled resets the state. you want to `return state` instead.